# Is it possible to get permalinks to Google Drive files?

Tags: file-sharing, url, google-drive, cloud-storage

I have some files I will upload to Google Drive and share them online. But I will update these files frequently and when I do, I want the links to stay the same. Is this possible?

If I am not wrong, Google Drive is creating a new link each time the file is changed. How can I make this permanent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google Drive creates a different link each time the file is changed.

This is a link to a file I created just to test this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfoQ58ZYatJbOqacgN3cwKUz0QqMzFmO/view?usp=sharing

I initially saved a simple text file in my Google Drive.
Then I asked Google Drive (online) for the shareable link, and copied it.
Then I re-opened the document (on my desktop PC ) and pasted that link into the document, then saved it.
Then I went back to Google Drive, confirmed that the document reflected the change and requested a shareable link.
Then I re-opened the document (on my desktop), pasted that link to the document, and saved it.

I then added those two links to the document again, right next to each other, to make it easier to compare them.  The links are the same.

QED (I hope) -- that link will take people to whatever the current status of the document is in your Google Drive online.

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing.